# Two separate background images

Tags: css

I want to have my page to have two background images: one at the top, and one at the bottom. I don't want them static, though. How would I do this?

Comment: A little more info would be helpful, as prodigitalson pointed out. A mockup would be very helpful too. There are a lot of variables here and a lot of different ways to do this with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you need the page to look like and what the background images are. If you want a **solution** you need to post more detail preferably with a composite image of whatthe page should look like and an example of the images by themselves.

that said one way might be:

```
html {backgoround: trasnparent url(/path/to/image) scroll no-repeat top center;}
body {backgoround: trasnparent url(/path/to/other-image) scroll no-repeat bottom center;}
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is have the first image to be on the top of the page (like with "background: url(/path/to/image) repeat-x;"). The second image is along the bottom of the page. So, when you scroll down to the end of the page, it's along the bottom.

Comment: right but you arent alays going to have a set page height are you? How do you need the images to behave when the page is short, long, normal etc.? Do you need a solid color in between? is this color associated with the top of the bottom graphic or the bottom of the top graphic?

Answer (score 2):

Make two nested layers with zero margin and padding, like so:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <!-- Page goes here. -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Then have a separate background-image for outer and inner, one fixed to the top, one fixed to the bottom:

```
.outer {
  background-position: bottom;
  // ...
}

.inner {
  background-position: top;
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use divs with background images and place them appropriately either using your layout or with the positioning attributes. You could take the one for the top, put it in a div that is absolutely positioned and z-indexed to be underneath your regular page. Then the other one could be put in the body style and positioned at the bottom.